# Import/commit to svn branch from a different codebase

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to migrate to svn from a not-so-famous version control system (lets call it ***nsfvc***). svn trunk was created some time ago from nsfvc's trunk. There is an active branch in nsfvc that I have to import to svn branch. The diff between nsfvc's trunk and branch is huge (updates, renames, additions, deletions, moves).

How do I go about doing this? I am guessing it is not as simple as...

```
svn co http://mysvn/repo/branches/branch c:\workspace
# replace files in c:\workspace
svn add
svn ci
```

Comment: Unless you're running into a problem that should work right?

Comment: @John W I did not try it yet, although I ran some tests in my sandbox. Didn't want to miss out on anything. So, checking with you guys.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. It's probably too late to suggest, but if this is the first time you guys will be using SVN you might want to consider migrating instead to a DVCS such as mercurial or git. They have better support for merging and branching, so using one could make your life much easier over the long-term...

Comment: I don't follow -- does the SVN branch already exist, or are you creating it for the first time?

Comment: @William L It does not exist yet. But, I will have to run a copy command to create it from the trunk, so in essence, the svn branch will exist before I do any sort of migration.

Comment: I will proceed with my plan and update the question.

Comment: Why do you have to do the copy from trunk?  Why not import directly from the old version ctrl system into the branch?

Comment: @William L Won't that somehow break the link b/w trunk and branch, since the branch has no parent? Curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding, but my advice is:

- create the svn branch from the nsfvc branch the same way you created the svn trunk from the nsfvc trunk.  (I assume svn import?)
- at this point you should have mirrored the state of the nsfvc repository in the svn repository
- you should now be free to svn merge between the svn trunk and svn branch.  svn merge is simply the process of applying diffs.  You needn't setup some special connection between the trunk and the branch.
- assuming you are running svn 1.5.x or 1.6.x, you can use svn mergeinfo to track subsequent merges between the trunk and branch

Comment: Question: When a branch is created by running svn copy, svn does not duplicate all the files. It does a "soft copy." If I resort to importing into the branch, this will not happen. I am still leaning towards my plan (in my question). What do you think?

Comment: You are correct. ("cheap copy" is SVN's term)  If you import into the branch, it will occupy as much hard drive space as the initial import into trunk.  Of course any subsequent actions would be cheap copies.  Is that really an issue?  I don't see that you're really losing anything since this is a one-time only thing you're doing (i.e. setting up the branch) and hard drive space isn't so scarce these days...

Comment: You're gonna hate me for this :) I followed my plan, and everything looks good. Accepted for diligence.